# How to select particular substring which appears after specific word in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have column values something like this

```
"{"key1":val1,"key1":val1,"key3":val3,"key4":val4}"
```

& I need to get all the values of "key3"

Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like a JSON string, why not use the JSON functions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: interesting... let me go through that... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a [substring](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)?
Like [there](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2889a/5/0)?